# How do I perform an Iris Wipe transition, using C++ in SDL 2.0?

Tags: c++, graphics, graphics-programming, sdl2

How do I perform image masking/clipping using an arbitrary shape like a circle?

I want to do an Iris Wipe transition, similar to in the movies. By Iris transition, I mean the circle transition effect where it starts with a small circle, and zoomed in to reveal the scene.

How do I accomplish it in SDL 2.0 with C++?

Comment: And just to clarify, you use SDL's rendering functionality for rendering? And you want a circle that slowly scales up, displaying what's under it and everything else on the screen black?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start by creating an image that acts as the mask part.

[image: Iris Mas]

Next, pick the on-screen location where you want the center of the circle be. Let's call that point `(X, Y)`. So, what you want to do, is gradually increase the size of the circle, and center it around the point you picked. You also want to fill the rest of the screen with black, and only render the game below the mask image. (Note that the circle part of the mask should be transparent.)

So, the program flow would go as follows:

1. At the start of your frame, clear the screen with black (you probably already do this).
2. Calculate the size of your mask texture. Basically you would just declare a variable `int size = 0;`, and increment that each frame by a fitting amount. You would then use this value to calculate the destination rectangle for the sprite. It would be something like `SDL_Rect dest = {X - size / 2, Y - size / 2, size, size};`.
3. Now that you have the destination rectangle calculated, before rendering your actual game objects, call `SDL_RenderSetClipRect(renderer, &dest);`. This assures that nothing is rendered outside of the (square) circle texture area. That way everything outside of the texture should stay black.
4. Finally, simply render your mask texture onto the screen: `SDL_RenderCopy(renderer, maskTexture, NULL, &dest);`.
5. As a last step, you probably need to figure out when the effect has finished. This might be a little tricky, but basically you just want to calculate when your screen "box" fits perfectly inside your circle. That shouldn't be too tricky, as you could probably get away by just checking if all the corners of your screen are within the circle.

Comment: It works, thanks!
ill just add some detail, it needs to draw the circle on top of the scene like an overlay then perform the clip.

Comment: That doesn't sound right. Clipping needs to happen before rendering the scene. In any case, I'm happy this helped!